# Hol Hamo'ed Pesach Torah reading procedure

Tags: passover, torah-service, kaddish, chol-hamoed

On weekdays of Hol Hamo'ed Pesach we take out 2 Sifrei Torah.

After the 3rd aliyah, the 2nd Torah is placed next to the 1st and hagbah is done on the 1st. We then read from the 2nd.

Q - Before saying Half Kaddish, does the 1st Torah need to be returned to the table to say Kaddish on both of them?

**Note**: This coming Shabbat (Vayikra/Rosh Chodesh/Hachodesh) with 3 Sifrei Torah has a similar situation. Perhaps, the fact that there is a maftir, and Kaddish separates the 7th aliyah from maftir, maybe there are different rules than Hol Hamo'ed which doesn't have maftir?

Comment: How many of the 3 Sifrei Torah will be on the Bimah this Shabbat during Kaddish, which is also recited after reading the 2nd one. (I'll be well placed to see what we do as I'm going to get called up for the 3rd one)

Comment: @CashCow - It has been a few years since we had 3 on Shabbat. However, Shabbat has maftir, so, perhaps, there are different rules.

Comment: Yes this Shabbat will have a 3rd Torah for Maftir but it's the same in that the main k'riya is from the first 2 sifrei torah and that the kaddish is recited after the 2nd one.

Comment: Last week we had 2, and they placed the first on the bimah before kaddish.

Comment: The situation was different though as you recited the kaddish (on Parshat Parah) after the first Torah and before the second, rather than after the second one.

This Shabbat the 2nd Torah (Rosh Chodesh) reading forms the last of the 7 regular Aliyot.

Answer (score 2):

In an analogous case (where three scrolls are used, one for the first six *aliyos*, another for the seventh, then *kadish*, then the third scroll for *maftir*), the *Shaare Efrayim* (10:12) says one "need not" ("א״צ") put the first scroll near the second and third when saying *kadish*. He sort-of implies that the same is true in your case of *chol hamoed Pesach* (since he mentions that case at the start of the paragraph and doesn't explicitly differentiate it), though he isn't 100% clear on that.

The *L'vush* ("*Minhagim*" 24 at the end of *OC*) says we don't put the first scroll down for *kadish* when there are there scrolls (or when we say *kadish* after the second scroll on *Rosh Chodesh Teves*) because "they already read from the first, and everyone knows the *kadish* applies back to it also". Presumably the same would apply to your case of *chol hamoed Pesach*, though he doesn't say so explicitly.

However, *Rav Yaakov Emden*'s *sidur Bes Yaakov* (שער המפקד מבוי ח מסילה א אות יז) says that the first scroll is placed near the second for *kadish* on *chol hamoed Pesach*.